# setting fixed values to X axis of a chart

Tags: c#, mschart

The problem is that I want to set some fixed values for 3 types of charts:

1. First is a week chart so it need to have Sunday to Saturday values on X axis.
2. Second is month so it have to set the days of the current month
3. The last one its a year chart that need to show months from 1 to 12 or jan to dec.

I did watch a lot of tutorials but any of those set points like I want and most of them teach how to set X and Y points, but I want a fixed X point and get the Y point from the DB.

[image: This is an example of what I need]

Comment: I didn't even know there was a WinForms Chart control. But, it looks there's an Axis class in the same namespace.  Have you tried using that? If so, what does your code look like? You will not likely get a useful answer on this site if you don't post your code and explain your issue in terms of that code.

Comment: You should set the right properties of the Series and the  x-axis. Set the series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime and then set the right ax.IntervalType, ax.LabelStyle.Format. After selecting the correct range of dates set the ax.Minimum and ax.Maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get these fixed ranges :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have set up the chart like so:

```
private void rb_range_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Chart chart = chart8;
    Series s = chart.Series[0];
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    s.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
    Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    //ax.IsMarginVisible = true;  // max or may be necessary

    ax.Interval = 1;

    if (rb_week.Checked)
    {
        setValues('w', 123);

        ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        ax.LabelStyle.Format = "dddd";
    }
    else if (rb_month.Checked)
    {
        setValues('m', 123);
        ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        ax.LabelStyle.Format = "dd";
    }
    else if (rb_year.Checked)
    {
        setValues('y', 123);
        ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        ax.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMM";
    }
    s.Points.Clear();
    foreach (var dp in points)  s.Points.Add(dp);
    // after the points are added or bound to you may want to..
    // set the minimum&maximum, but if the data fit you don't have to!
    ax.Minimum = points.Min(x => x.XValue); 
    ax.Maximum = points.Max(x => x.XValue); 
}
```

A few Notes :

- It is important to select or bind only those dates that should go into the chart! If you make mistakes here the limits will be off!
- If your data are dense enough, that is, if they inclused the 1st and last day of the interval they refer to, you can omit setting the Minimum and Maximum on the x-axis; in that case also include `ax.IsMarginVisible = false;` to avoid points from the neighboring ranges showing up.
- If you data are sparse you may need to determine the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values differently than simply picking the first and last x-values. Instead you should pick the correct `DateTime` values. Note that you need to pick real  `DateTimes` and convert them to `double` with the `ToOADate()` function, as the axis properties expect value units.
- You can study the code I used to create my data for hints on how to get the Date of the 1st and last day of a given week, month or year..
- Note how I use `DateTime.DaysInMonth` to get the correct number of days in a given month
- If you chose `Column` as `ChartType` the 1st and last columns may get cut. For this case you can expand the range by adding half a unit to the `Maximum` and subtracting the same from the `Minimum`. You may also need to add one such amount to the `IntervalOffset`.

Here is how I set up the `points`:

```
List<DataPoint> points = new List<DataPoint>();

void setValues(char time, int rand)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(rand);  // random data values
    points = new List<DataPoint>();
    DateTime dn = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dw = new DateTime(dn.Year, dn.Month, dn.Day % 7 + 1); //my weeks start on monday
    DateTime dm = new DateTime(dn.Year, dn.Month, 1);
    DateTime dy = new DateTime(dn.Year, 1, 1);

    if (time == 'w') for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            points.Add(new DataPoint(dw.AddDays(i).ToOADate(), rnd.Next(100) + 50));
    if (time == 'm') for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(dn.Year, dn.Month); i++)
            points.Add(new DataPoint(dm.AddDays(i).ToOADate(), rnd.Next(100) + 50));
    if (time == 'y') for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            points.Add(new DataPoint(dy.AddMonths(i).ToOADate(), rnd.Next(100) + 50));
}
```

Comment: im gonna try this. but looks exactly like i want to do. thank you very much